# Fourier Transform of a Sampling Function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, fourier-transform

I have trouble trying to work out a fourier transform of sampling function. I also looked at other questions on math stackexchange but they just don't make much sense to me.

\begin{equation}
f(t)=\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{T}{\Delta t}-1} \delta(t-j\Delta t) \text{ where, } T=n\Delta t 
\end{equation}

I'm not even sure how to approach this problem - I'm not sure how the delta function inside of the sum works out to be when you apply the fourier transform.
I think that you should get something like this - but also, I'm not really sure.

\begin{equation}
f(\omega)=\sum_{j=0}^{\Delta t-1} \delta(\omega-j\frac{T}{\Delta t})
\end{equation}

Comment: The Fourier transform is linear, so applying to a sum of things just means: apply it to each thing and sum the results. Do you know or can you calculate the Fourier transform of a single delta function?

Comment: Well I know that fourier transformation of delta function $\delta(x-x_0) = e^{-2\pi ikx_0}$.... so in this case, I would get $\delta(t-j\Delta t)=e^{-2 \pi ik(j\Delta t)}$ ... am I right here?